# Feature Extraction

Tags: feature-selection, feature-extraction

I've a data set for different sensor values(like voltage, pressure, vibration etc) for a machine. I need to extract features from it to be able to do predictive maintenance. Which features should i look for ?

Comment: Hi Fahad! I recommend to you my paper Generic Data Imputation and Feature Extraction for Signals from Multifunctional Printers http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2322/dsi4-1.pdf, that describes how to prepare IoT data for further predictive maintenance.